# How to emulate full outer join in this query?

Tags: mysql, full-outer-join

So apparently mySQL doesn't support full outer join, but it's really what I need. I've seen a bunch of blog posts and articles about emulating it with unions, but that removes duplicates. Can anyone help me out here?

Here's the query containing the full outer join (only one of a number of joins being done here); how would I translate that into something mySQL understands?

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.title, nr.teaser, n.nid, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created), '%M %e, %Y') AS date, f.filepath AS image,tn_img.tid as image_tid

FROM node n 

JOIN node_revisions nr ON n.nid = nr.nid 
LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri ON (n.nid = cfri.nid AND cfri.delta = 0) 
LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
LEFT JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid   
JOIN term_node tn2 ON n.nid = tn2.nid 
FULL OUTER JOIN term_node tn_img ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = tn_img.nid

WHERE n.status = 1 
AND n.type = 'article'   
AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
AND tn2.tid = 143

ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: You might want to a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/mysql-full-outer-join-syntax-error

Comment: I had already read those (and all the linked articles/posts), but could not extrapolate what they were suggesting to my query. This is really stretching the limits of my sql knowledge.

Comment: Thats cool. You might want to consider adding references to the questions you looked at to stop the question from being closed as duplicate... and of course snarky comments.

Comment: @EmmyS: Conrad Frix...well answered......!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically do a Union of LEFT and RIGHT JOIN.

You actually have interesting wrinkle in that you also want to limit the rows to 3. To solve that you need to

- Limit both The "left" and "right" selects by 3
- Then use the result of the UNION in a inline view
- then Limit the union by 3 again

**UPDATE** Sadly, unless I'm mistaken you can't do this directly in a UNION so you need to add another layer  of inline views prior to the UNION

The LIMITS inside the UNION will offer some performance benefit and then the limit after will give you the correct results.

```
SELECT title, 
   teaser, 
   nid, 
   DATE, 
   image, 
   image_tid 
FROM   (SELECT title, 
               teaser, 
               nid, 
               DATE, 
               image, 
               image_tid,
               created 
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT n.title, 
                                nr.teaser, 
                                n.nid, 
                                Date_format(From_unixtime(n.created), 
                                '%M %e, %Y') AS 
                                DATE, 
                                f.filepath 
                                AS 
                                image, 
                                tn_img.tid 
                                AS 
                                image_tid 
                                       , 
                                n.created 
                FROM   node n 
                       JOIN node_revisions nr 
                         ON n.nid = nr.nid 
                       LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri 
                         ON ( n.nid = cfri.nid 
                              AND cfri.delta = 0 ) 
                       LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf 
                         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
                       LEFT JOIN files f 
                         ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid 
                       JOIN term_node tn2 
                         ON n.nid = tn2.nid 
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN term_node tn_img 
                         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = tn_img.nid 
                WHERE  n.status = 1 
                       AND n.TYPE = 'article' 
                       AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
                       AND tn2.tid = 143 
                ORDER  BY n.created DESC 
                LIMIT  3) tleft 
        UNION 
        SELECT title, 
               teaser, 
               nid, 
               DATE, 
               image, 
               image_tid,
               created  
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT n.title, 
                                nr.teaser, 
                                n.nid, 
                                Date_format(From_unixtime(n.created), 
                                '%M %e, %Y') AS 
                                DATE, 
                                f.filepath 
                                AS 
                                image, 
                                tn_img.tid 
                                AS 
                                image_tid 
                                       , 
                                n.created 
                FROM   node n 
                       JOIN node_revisions nr 
                         ON n.nid = nr.nid 
                       LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri 
                         ON ( n.nid = cfri.nid 
                              AND cfri.delta = 0 ) 
                       LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf 
                         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
                       LEFT JOIN files f 
                         ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid 
                       JOIN term_node tn2 
                         ON n.nid = tn2.nid 
                       RIGHT OUTER JOIN term_node tn_img 
                         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = tn_img.nid 
                WHERE  n.status = 1 
                       AND n.TYPE = 'article' 
                       AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
                       AND tn2.tid = 143 
                ORDER  BY n.created DESC 
                LIMIT  3) tright) t 
ORDER  BY created DESC 
LIMIT  3
```

**UPDATE**
Using spencer7593 and ypercube suggestions here's an alternative approach using  two UNION ALL statements  and no inline views.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.created, 
                n.title, 
                nr.teaser, 
                n.nid, 
                Date_format(From_unixtime(n.created), '%M %e, %Y') AS DATE, 
                f.filepath                                         AS image, 
                tn_img.tid                                         AS image_tid 
FROM   node n 
       JOIN node_revisions nr 
         ON n.nid = nr.nid 
       LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri 
         ON ( n.nid = cfri.nid 
              AND cfri.delta = 0 ) 
       LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf 
         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
       LEFT JOIN files f 
         ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid 
       JOIN term_node tn2 
         ON n.nid = tn2.nid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN term_node tn_img 
         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = tn_img.nid 
WHERE  n.status = 1 
       AND n.TYPE = 'article' 
       AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
       AND tn2.tid = 143 

UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT n.created, 
                n.title, 
                nr.teaser, 
                n.nid, 
                Date_format(From_unixtime(n.created), '%M %e, %Y') AS DATE, 
                f.filepath                                         AS image, 
                tn_img.tid                                         AS image_tid 
FROM   node n 
       JOIN node_revisions nr 
         ON n.nid = nr.nid 
       LEFT JOIN content_field_related_images cfri 
         ON ( n.nid = cfri.nid 
              AND cfri.delta = 0 ) 
       LEFT JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf 
         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = cfaf.nid 
       LEFT JOIN files f 
         ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid 
       JOIN term_node tn2 
         ON n.nid = tn2.nid 
       RIGHT JOIN term_node tn_img 
         ON cfri.field_related_images_nid = tn_img.nid 
WHERE  n.status = 1 
       AND n.TYPE = 'article' 
       AND nr.body LIKE '%kimberly-clark%' 
       AND tn2.tid = 143 
       AND cfri.field_related_images_nid IS NULL 
ORDER  BY 1 DESC 
LIMIT 
3
```

Comment: Wow, that's scary-looking! I'll give it a shot and see what it returns. Thanks.

Comment: OK, just tried it and got this: #1054 - Unknown column 'created' in 'order clause'. I tried changing the final order by clause to n.created, but it gave me the same error, so I'm not sure what it's referring to. Also, could you explain what cfri.delta = 0 refers to?

Comment: @Emmy -- in a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` query, the `ORDER BY` clause references columns by position rather than by name (e.g. to get the result set ordered by the first column in the result set,  `ORDER BY 1`).  Also consider using a `UNION ALL` rather than a `UNION` to avoid elimination of duplicate rows.

Comment: @EmmyS. Sorry about that I forgot to include created in `tright` and `tleft` I updated the answer

Comment: @spencer7593 - the issue with the order by is that we're trying to order the records by a column that isn't actually included in the outer query to display (created) - so how do we handle that?

Comment: @spencer7593 when emulating `FULL OUTER JOIN` you actually do want `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`

Comment: @Conrad - actually, it is possible to use a UNION ALL in a query that emulates a FULL OUTER JOIN (which you would want to do to preserve duplicates) using three queries: an inner join, a left join and a right join.  e.g. `SELECT . FROM l INNER JOIN r  UNION ALL  SELECT . FROM l LEFT JOIN r WHERE r.id IS NULL  UNION ALL  SELECT . FROM l RIGHT JOIN r WHERE l.id IS NULL`

Comment: @spencer7593 Added alternative using your suggestions.

Comment: Excuse for breaking into without having read the entire query, but can't a `FULL OUTER JOIN` be done using a `UNION ALL` of 2 queries: `(SELECT . FROM l LEFT JOIN r) UNION ALL (SELECT . FROM l RIGHT JOIN r WHERE l.id IS NULL)` ?

Comment: @Emmy - unfortunately, the only way I know to <b>guarantee</b> that a result set from a UNION query is returned in a specific order is to `ORDER BY` columns referenced by position. (At least, that's been my experience. If I don't include an ORDER BY on the outermost query, then (according to the SQL spec), the database engine is free to return the tuples (rows) in whatever order it wants to.

Comment: @ypercube - yes, my bad, the inner join and one of the outer joins can be collapsed, so it would be two queries, just like you suggest.)