# MySQL Joining 3 tables with 2 common attributes

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables with the following structure:

**Table_A:**

- `Date`, `ID`, `A1`, `A2`.

**Table_B:**

- `Date`, `ID`, `B1`.

**Table_C:**

- `Date`, `ID`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`.

I want to join all three into a table with attributes: `Date`, `ID`, `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`.

For the 3 tables some of the Dates and IDs are the same but some are not so I want to do something like a `LEFT JOIN` with a `UNION` and then `RIGHT JOIN` so that I don't lose any of the Date and ID rows. It seems like I need the Date and ID combinations to get their own unique identifiers so that I can then join the tables but I have hit a road block.

Comment: Sound like you want a FULL OUTER JOIN, unfortunately mysql does not support it.  Your idea of using UNION is probably the best way to go about it.  Check this our for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/mysql-full-outer-join-syntax-error

Answer (score 3):

You might try this one:

```
SELECT Date, ID, A1, A2, B1, C1, C2, C3
FROM (
    SELECT Date, ID
    FROM Table_A
    UNION
    SELECT Date, ID
    FROM Table_B
    UNION
    SELECT Date, ID
    FROM Table_B
) d
LEFT JOIN Table_A a on (d.Date=a.Date and d.ID=a.ID)
LEFT JOIN Table_B b on (d.Date=b.Date and d.ID=b.ID)
LEFT JOIN Table_C c on (d.Date=c.Date and d.ID=c.ID)
```

This should give you the answer you are looking for, however I assume that the statement will be quite slow for large sets of data.

Comment: This is the error that I keep getting when trying your above suggestion: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd
LEFT JOIN ....

Comment: fixed the error, thanks for pointing it out (I removed the `dates` alias from the subselect table)

Comment: Unfortunately my data set is very large , over 300,000 rows for just Table_A. I ran the query for an hour and a half before I stopped it. Do you have any suggestions for a query that might be faster? Thank you so much.