# How do I create a correct statement for MySQL JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have `user` table and `payment` is many to many relationships table.

```
SELECT user.uID,
       user.uName,
       user.uLocation,
       user.uBlock,
       user.uRoom,
       user.uStatus,
       payment.pID,
       payment.pDate,
       payment.pType
FROM   user
       INNER JOIN payment
         ON user.uID = payment.pID
LIMIT  0,100
```

1. With `INNER JOIN` results will be nothing.
2. With `LEFT JOIN` **user** display correct result but return `NULL` on **payment** table
3. With `RIGHT JOIN` **payment** display correct result but return `NULL` on **user** table

How do I get a correct result to display both? `LEFT JOIN` & `RIGHT JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

```
SELECT user.uID,
       user.uName,
       user.uLocation,
       user.uBlock,
       user.uRoom,
       user.uStatus,
       payment.pID,
       payment.pDate,
       payment.pType
FROM   user
       FULL OUTER JOIN payment
         ON user.uID = payment.pID
LIMIT  0,100
```

> **Full outer join**
>
> **Conceptually, a full outer join combines the effect of applying both left and right outer joins.** Where records in the FULL OUTER JOINed tables do not match, the result set will have NULL values for every column of the table that lacks a matching row. For those records that do match, a single row will be produced in the result set (containing fields populated from both tables).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join)

---

For `MySQL` read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384312/601179), you should use `UNION`

Comment: Sorry.. I have edited question tag. Looks like no `FULL OUTER JOIN` for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You're demanding that user id equals payment id.  You're lucky if that returns an empty set, it could also return completely wrong data :)  It should probably be:

```
user.uID = payment.uID
```

Or `payment.userId`, or something.  Check the columns in the payments table.

Comment: Hmmm.. actually `pID` column will store the `user.uID`