# MySQL - how do I do an outer join where either side is optional - left and right outer join

Tags: mysql

I need to join 2 MySQL tables that will return rows if Either side of the join exists, and only one row if both side exist.

Here is a a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` INT(11) ,
  `qty` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` INT(11) ,
  `price` DECIMAL(8,2)  DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT  INTO `a`(`id`,`qty`) VALUES (1,1),(3,0);
INSERT  INTO `b`(`id`,`price`) VALUES (1,'10.00'),(2,'20.00');

SELECT * FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id;
returns 1 and 3

SELECT * FROM b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.id=b.id;
returns 1 and 2


SELECT * FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
  UNION
SELECT * FROM b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.id=b.id;
returns 1, 3, 1 , 2 

SELECT * FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
  UNION
SELECT * FROM b 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN a ON a.id=b.id;
returns 1, 3, 1
```

Is this possible in MySQL to get 1,2,3  or do I have to program around it?

Comment: So, are you just wanting to get the `id` from each table, if `id` exists in both return `id`, `price` and `qty`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which, unfortunately, is not implemented in MySQL. You can achieve the same with a union, however. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join) for how to do this.