# Full Join Not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join, myisam

Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb282/2)

And here is my Query :

```
select employee.eid, staff.acc_no from employee FULL JOIN staff on employee.eid = staff.eid
```

I can able to do join, left join, right join but not full join. It says the error

```
Unknown column 'employee.eid' in 'field list': select employee.eid, staff.acc_no from employee FULL JOIN staff on employee.eid = staff.eid
```

What is the mistake i am doing ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/1729885

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Outer Join in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Niels pointed out firstly you dont have full joins in mysql.

I would recommend you to read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html).

However you can emulate outer join with the help of a `UNION` operator.

The detailed explanation could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join) as well

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support `full outer join`.  However, your tables should have proper foreign key relationships, so it should not be necessary:

```
select employee.eid, staff.acc_no
from employee INNER JOIN
     staff
     on employee.eid = staff.eid;
```

If they don't, you can use the `union all`/`group by` approach:

```
select eid, max(accno) as accno
from (select e.eid, NULL as acc_no from employee e union all
      select s.eid, s.acc_no from staff
     ) se
group by eid;
```

Comment: Awesome, alternate way +1

Comment: @gordon Linoff this wont work ..check the second code writeup