# How to join two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I want to show all records from table `A` and join with `B`, I have tried left and right join.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, desired results, and the query that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an outer join, and I believe your question is very similar to this one: [Why does MySQL report a syntax error on FULL OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join)