# Select from 2 unrelated tables and merge unique ID columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return a combined result of data from 2 tables, but need to merge the ID column from both to form one result set, the full outer join is the closest I have to returning the correct row number.

Example:

T1

```
ID  A
a   s
b   s
e   s
f   s
```

T2

```
ID  B
a   a
c   a
d   a
f   a
```

Result

```
ID   A      B
a    s      a
b    s      NULL
c    NULL   a
d    NULL   a
e    s      NULL
f    s      a



    declare @t1 table (
                  ID varchar(1),
                  A varchar(1)
                 )
insert into @t1 values ('a','s')
insert into @t1 values ('b','s')
insert into @t1 values ('e','s')
insert into @t1 values ('f','s')

declare @t2 table (
                  ID varchar(1),
                  B varchar(1)
                 )

insert into @t2 values ('a','a')
insert into @t2 values ('c','a')
insert into @t2 values ('d','a')
insert into @t2 values ('f','a')

select * from @t1
select * from @t2
```

Comment: Did you try `Full JOIN` ?

Comment: Yes, the full join returns the correct number of rows, but doesnt combine the unique value of the ID column into one column, you get 2 ID columns.

Comment: @WayneCrick Which database you are using? mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL; you don't have FULL JOINS in MySQL, but you can surely [emulate them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html).

For a code SAMPLE transcribed from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/mysql-full-outer-join-syntax-error) you have:

with two tables t1, t2:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

So your query becomes:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) As ID, t1.A As A, t2.B As B FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) As ID, t1.A As A, t2.B As B FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
order by ID
```

It gives me correct result with your inputs as:

```
ID   A      B
a    s      a
b    s      NULL
c    NULL   a
d    NULL   a
e    s      NULL
f    s      a
```

Comment: Hi @Avidan, this works for me, thank you, I have not looked at COALESCE before, have learned something new.. many thanks

Comment: you know that You are basically doing full join with your query but with long way around.

Comment: @CoderofCode Yes Buddy. Am doing it as there is no FULL Outer JOIN in MySQL as I know. Please go through the links I posted in answer. (By the way do u have any shorter way to do it?)

Comment: @CoderofCode By the way; I gone through your answer too. :) I guess it will work with SQL Server. It didn't work with me on mysql.

Comment: Question was tagged with `SQL server`  first the `mysql` tag was not there at the time of the writing an answer. By adding that tag OP made answer look stupid.

Comment: @CoderofCode Nope buddy. He had added both the tags. Please go through the edit history. So I asked him... `Which database you are using?` and as already you posted an answer for ms sql server; I choose to post fr MySQL as my answer should `not look` your copy paste :)

Comment: @CoderofCode By the way you would not have deleted the answer. I was just searching to upvote it, as logic is correct and question has `sql server`  tag too. With many deleted posts(answers) Stack Overflow can ban from posting answers :( :)

Comment: It will not make any sense to upvote it. Due to the fact that OP wanted to for `MySql`. It will not do any good.

Comment: @CoderofCode Buddy answers are upvoted when those are right; no matter OP accepts those or not. Your answer was correct based on question. But now Am sorry. Right now tags are removed :( Oh.. You itself removed it.. Great guy :) and good attitude :)

Comment: I removed the tags to match what OP wanted. The upvote doesn't matter to me. It just some lousy points.so mehh no problem there :)

Comment: Just to note, I'm using MSSQL 2012, next time I will be clearer on the technical details, this is my first post :)