# Why is this sql query failing on outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
        SELECT tmp1.post_parent, external_qty, internal_qty
        FROM (
            SELECT wp_posts.post_parent, SUM(wp_shoesol_inventory.qty) as external_qty
            FROM wp_posts
            INNER JOIN wp_variation_sku ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_variation_sku.variation_id)
            INNER JOIN wp_shoesol_inventory ON (wp_shoesol_inventory.sku = wp_variation_sku.sku )
            GROUP BY wp_posts.post_parent
        ) as tmp1
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT wp_posts.post_parent, SUM(wp_storage_manager.product_quantity) as internal_qty
            FROM wp_posts
            INNER JOIN wp_variation_sku ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_variation_sku.variation_id)
            INNER JOIN wp_storage_manager ON (wp_storage_manager.variation_id = wp_variation_sku.sku )
            GROUP BY wp_posts.post_parent
        ) as tmp2 ON tmp1.post_parent = tmp2.post_parent
```

But it fails with the following message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN (
>               SELECT wp_posts.post_parent, SUM(wp_storage_manager.product' at line 9

Thanks to all the helpers!

Comment: MySQL has no full outer join support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join

Comment: MySQL dos not support `full outer join`.  You can probably use `union all` instead.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql