# PHP select multiple Array tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

Is it possible to `SELECT` with multiple Array tables. I know it sounds confusing but here is what I have done :

First of all, I've created a form, that has two checkboxes option as follows :

```
<form action="something.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="store[]" value="M1">
<input type="checkbox" name="store[]" value="M2">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Now after submitting the form, I can view which store selected by doing `foreach loop`:

```
$allstore = $_POST['store'];
 foreach ($allstore as $store=>$value) {
echo $value;
}
```

Everything till now works as needed !
However those two values in checkboxes are considered to be **table names** ! Now how can I find a way to let PHP select either one or two tables based on user selection `$value` ?

```
$query = "SELECT * from **{$allstore[0]},{$allstore[1]}** WHERE .....";
```

As you can see **{$allstore[0]},{$allstore[1]}** should be created based under foreach loop. I can't seem to find a way of doing it! Can I insert a function to do it for me?

Like this :     `$query = "SELECT * from ((( Function Here ))) WHERE .....";`

If you have a different way of doing it, Please share it.

---

Edit :

**M1 Table**

```
id |item_no |qty |price
1   x1       10   20
2   x2       5    22
3   x3       3    5
```

**M2 Table**

```
id |item_no |qty |price
1   x1      11    20
2   x9      5     30
3   x10     6     26
```

The output table should be

```
item_no | price |   M1 |  M2
x1         20       10    11
x2         22       5     N/A
x3         5        3     N/A
x9         30       N/A   5
x10        26       N/A   6
```

That's what I am aiming for. I hope it can be solved !

Comment: What should the output be if the user doesn't select all the tables? What goes in the `price` column if there's a different price in the two tables? What you want looks like `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which MySQL doesn't have; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql for a workaround.

Comment: Well, I can assure that the prices are fixed no matter what. Secondly , the user can not submit the form unless 1 checkbox is selected.

Comment: I meant what should the result be if they only select one table, not both. What goes in the M2 column if they only select M1?

Comment: If the prices are the same in all tables, this is bad normalization, there should be another table that contains the prices of the items.

Comment: Can there be more than 2 tables? Do you need a solution that works with any number of tables, or just 2?

Comment: I see what you mean, it will only show M1 column only, because I've made both store names as Arrays! ... And when I explode this array it will create <td> accordingly. Its works already for me right now.

Comment: Well its possible to be more than 2 tables.

Comment: See the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join) for how to emulate full outer join of more than 2 tables. You'll then need to write code to generate that dyncamically from the list of tables in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

here's the structure for 2 tables [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48e08/3)
I think you can add more tables from here.

```
SELECT T1.item_no,
  COALESCE(M1.price,M2.price) as price,
  M1.qty as M1,
  M2.qty as M2
FROM
  (SELECT item_no FROM M1
    UNION
   SELECT item_no FROM M2
   )T1
   LEFT JOIN M1 ON T1.item_no = M1.item_no
   LEFT JOIN M2 ON T1.item_no = M2.item_no
```

UPDATED: I am not too familiar with PHP but I looked up some syntax and was able to dynamically generate SQL based on array of either ["M1","M2"] or ["M1"] or ["M2"]

[DynamicPHPtobuildSQL](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df0bbe224b8d4d722028c72853f051a8dc31c4e7)

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$allstore = ["M2"];
$item = 0;
$sqlpart1 = "";
$sqlpart2 = "";
$sqlpart3 = "";
$sqlpart4 = "";
foreach ($allstore as $store=>$value) {
   $item += 1;
   if ($item > 1){
     $sqlpart1 .= ",";
     $sqlpart2 .= ",";
     $sqlpart3 .= " UNION ";
   }
   $sqlpart1 .= $value . ".price ";
   $sqlpart2 .= $value . ".qty as " . $value . " ";
   $sqlpart3 .= "SELECT item_no FROM " . $value . " ";
   $sqlpart4 .= "LEFT JOIN " . $value . " ON T1.item_no=" . $value . ".item_no ";
}
$SQL = "SELECT T1.item_no,COALESCE(" . $sqlpart1 . ") as price," . $sqlpart2;
$SQL .= "FROM (" . $sqlpart3 . ")T1 " . $sqlpart4;
echo $SQL;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this would come very handy if I know how to let user select which table he wants to see. I mean you have already assigned M1 and M2 without noticing that it needs to be checked from checkbox . In which it might be M1 only, Or M2 only ..Or Both. I've totally lost hope finding proper solution.

Comment: you can dynamically build up the SQL based on which ones are selected in PHP I think.. like the 
M1.price,M2.price can be built up...
M1.qty as M1,M2.qty as M2 can be built up...
SELECT item_no FROM M1 UNION SELECT item_no FROM M2 can be built up...
and same with LEFT JOIN M1 ON T1.item_no = M1.item_no LEFT JOIN M2 ON T1.item_no can be built up....based on what user selects you can just build up each pieces and concat the pieces together to build your final query

Comment: I have updated my answer with PHP code to give you idea on how you might dynamically generate SQL hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to avoid the risk of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection): compare the posted values against a closed list of existing store table names and reject any other value.

Note also that not only the `FROM` clause is influenced by the user's choices, but also the `SELECT` clause. So you have two dynamic parts in your SQL statement.

You could use this code which makes use of [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$selected_stores = $_POST['store'];

// Protect against SQL-injection by only accepting known tables:
$all_stores = array("M1", "M2", "M3");
$selected_stores = array_intersect($selected_stores, $all_stores);

// Build dynamic part of the FROM clause
$from = implode("
           UNION
           ", array_map(function ($store) { 
    return "SELECT '$store' as store, item_no, price, qty FROM $store";
}, $selected_stores));

// Build dynamic part of the SELECT clause
$cols = implode(",
     ", array_map(function ($store) { 
    return "CASE store WHEN '$store' THEN qty END AS $store";
}, $selected_stores));

$sql = "
SELECT   item_no,
         MAX(price) as price,
         $cols
FROM     ( $from ) data
GROUP BY item_no
";
```

The SQL generated looks like this:

```sql
SELECT   item_no,
         MAX(price) as price,
         CASE store WHEN 'M1' THEN qty END AS M1,
         CASE store WHEN 'M2' THEN qty END AS M2
FROM     ( SELECT 'M1' as store, item_no, price, qty FROM M1
           UNION
           SELECT 'M2' as store, item_no, price, qty FROM M2 ) data
GROUP BY item_no
```

See also [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7598/13).

As a side comment: I would advise to combine all store tables into one table, which would have an additional column indicating the store. This is more in line with normalised database design and will give more advantages than disadvantages in terms of searching, sorting, performance, and simplicity.