# SQL error on FULL OUTER JOIN sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a error in my SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM tireOverview FULL OUTER JOIN tirePrice ON tireOverview.ID=tirePrice.IDtire"
```

Where i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN tirePrice ON tireOverview.ID=tirePrice.IDtire ORDER BY tireOvervie...' at line 1 in /var/www/html/webscraper/scraper/include.php:158 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/webscraper/scraper/include.php(158): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/webscraper/scraper/index.php(34): tireReadOut(Object(PDO)) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/webscraper/scraper/include.php on line 158
```

My Database consists of 2 tables:

```
tireOverview -> ID, EAN, ProductName, Date, URLAutoweek

tirePrice -> ID, IDtire (fk tireOverview.ID), Seller(fk Sellers.ID), PriceAutoweek, PositionAutoweek, PriceJSON, LastChanged
```

I want to get all the data from where tireOverview.ID matches tirePrice.IDtire.

Database is mariaDB, with PHPMyAdmin.
Server is Debian 10 (Buster).
PHP is version 7.3.

If you need more info, just comment!

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB does not implement FULL joins.

Comment: Possible similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join

Comment: In MySQL you should use LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN. There is no just OUTER JOIN. If you need FULL OUTER JOIN in MySql you can use UNION of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar Thank you for directing me in the good direction, searched for 30 minutes but didn't find that page.

Comment: @Zegert Welcome !

Hope this will help you
SELECT * FROM company C
LEFT JOIN company_address A ON C.company_id = A.company_id
WHERE A.company_id IS NULL

Comment: If this is what you want:  "I want to get all the data from where tireOverview.ID matches tirePrice.IDtire.", then you merely want an inner join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As Akina said: "MySQL/MariaDB does not implement FULL joins.", but you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM company C LEFT JOIN company_address A ON C.company_id = A.company_id WHERE A.company_id IS NULL
```

Sources:

[How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

[[Why does MySQL report a syntax error on FULL OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Credits:
@Akina & @BhAvik Gajjar