# how to use full outer join by removing inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL I have one query which works perfectly fine with inner join but with inner join some records got missing I want all the  data from both the table but when i use full outer join or full join it gives error `unknown column classroom.id in field list`

**here is the query**

```
SELECT 
  classroom.id as id, 
  classroom.grade as grade,
  classroom.status as status, 
  teacher.id as tid, 
  teacher.name as tname 
FROM classroom
FULL JOIN teacher on classroom.teacherId = teacher.id 
ORDER BY grade ASC
```

these are my two tables you can see in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pinRS.png)

and also I mention in column

```
classroom 
id,grade,teacherid,status
teacher 
id,email,password,name,status,role
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support a `FULL OUTER JOIN` or `FULL JOIN`, you have to emulate it using `UNION` with `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

Read more about it here: [Why does MySQL report a syntax error on FULL OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join)

So your syntax should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
   a.id as id, 
   a.grade as grade,
   a.status as status, 
   b.id as tid, 
   b.name as tname 
 FROM classroom a
 LEFT JOIN teacher b ON a.teacherId = b.id 
   UNION
 SELECT 
   a.id as id, 
   a.grade as grade,
   a.status as status, 
   b.id as tid, 
   b.name as tname 
 FROM classroom a
 RIGHT JOIN teacher b ON a.teacherId = b.id) c
WHERE c.grade != '' AND c.grade IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c.grade ASC
```

**UPDATE:** Per your comments below, I've include a `WHERE` clause to remove `NULL` values `AND` empty `''` values. You could also write a `WHERE` clause in each of the `UNION` queries above but I find it easier to put it in a subquery and write the `WHERE` clause once in the outer query. I've also added aliases `a, b, c` so its easier to read vs. using the table names.

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/aUhbICpi).**

Comment: Yep, it might be interesting to note that `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` has been requested in MySQL since 2006 (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18003), but it's not been a priority to implement it. The workaround you show is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: can we enter a check that grade cannot be empty in this query

Comment: @FahaadMunir Sure can, empty `''` or `NULL`? or both?

Comment: but null is not working i  check is not null and its not working

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks Bill, that is interesting. I was surprised to find out it didn't support it. It would certainly minimize the amount of syntax.. one day...

Comment: @FahaadMunir does your grade column support `NULL` values?

Comment: @FahaadMunir I've updated my answer to exclude `NULL` and empty values for you.